# Linux 'ping' - Show when timeout occurrs?

Tags: linux, ping

Is there a way to make the Linux implementation of 'ping' to act like the Windows implementation in the way that it shows when a timeout occurs. I don't want it to exit, just show a timeout message.

We have some networking issues in the company and I would like to leave 'ping' to work over night and then grep through it to see if and when any timeouts occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
ping -c 1 -t 10  > /dev/null || date
```

in an infinite loop that runs the whole night?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see the time when timeout occurs, use this code

```
while :; do ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.0.254 > /dev/null && sleep 1 || echo "`date` >>> Request timed out"; done
```

**Example**

192.168.0.1 is responding to ping while 192.168.0.254 is not

```
[user@Linux ~]$ while :; do ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.0.1 > /dev/null && sleep 1 || echo "`date` >>> Request timed out"; done
^Z
[28]+  Stopped                 sleep 1
[user@Linux ~]$ 

[user@Linux ~]$ while :; do ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.0.254 > /dev/null && sleep 1 || echo "`date` >>> Request timed out"; done
Wed Jan  3 03:51:23 GMT 2018 >>> Request timed out
Wed Jan  3 03:51:24 GMT 2018 >>> Request timed out
Wed Jan  3 03:51:25 GMT 2018 >>> Request timed out
^Z
[30]+  Stopped                 ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.0.254 >/dev/null
[user@Linux ~]$
```

If you want to perform continuous ping just like windows and with timestamp, use this one.
Feel free to replace `192.168.0.1` with your own IP Address

```
while :; do ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.0.1 > /dev/null && echo "`date` >>> Reply OK" && sleep 1 || echo "`date` >>> Request timed out"; done
```

**Example Reply OK**

```
[user@Linux ~]$ while :; do ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.0.1 > /dev/null && echo "`date` >>> Reply OK" && sleep 1 || echo "`date` >>> Request timed out"; done
Wed Jan  3 03:41:49 GMT 2018 >>> Reply OK
Wed Jan  3 03:41:50 GMT 2018 >>> Reply OK
Wed Jan  3 03:41:51 GMT 2018 >>> Reply OK
^Z
[23]+  Stopped                 sleep 1
[user@Linux ~]$
```

**Example Request timed out**

```
[user@Linux ~]$ while :; do ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.0.254 > /dev/null && echo "`date` >>> Reply OK" && sleep 1 || echo "`date` >>> Request timed out"; done
Wed Jan  3 03:41:36 GMT 2018 >>> Request timed out
Wed Jan  3 03:41:37 GMT 2018 >>> Request timed out
Wed Jan  3 03:41:38 GMT 2018 >>> Request timed out
^Z
[22]+  Stopped                 ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.0.254 >/dev/null
[user@Linux ~]$
```